# Jetpack Compose Navigation default value not working for boolean

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Trying to send a default value of boolean type through to one of my screens using compose navigation, but the default value never gets applied - can anyone see what the issue might be here?

route declaration ->

```
    sealed class Screens(
    val coreRoute: String,
    val routeWithArgs: String? = null
) {

    fun navigateWithArgs(
        navController: NavController,
        coreRoute: String,
        args: List<Any>
    ) {
        navController.navigate("$coreRoute/${args.joinToString("/")}")
    }

    object Splash : Screens(coreRoute = "splash")
    object Establish : Screens(
        coreRoute = "establish",
        routeWithArgs = "establish/{isChanging}"
    )
 }
```

Screen setup ->

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
fun NavGraphBuilder.addEstablishScreen(
    navController: NavController
) {
    Screens.Establish.routeWithArgs?.let { route ->
        composable(
            route = route,
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("isChanging") {
                defaultValue = false
                type = NavType.BoolType
            })
        ) {
            EstablishComposable(
                navigateToHome = {
                    navController.navigate(Screens.Home.coreRoute)
                },
                navigateBack = {
                    navController.navigateUp()
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Navigating to screen ->

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
fun NavGraphBuilder.addSplashScreen(
    navController: NavController
) {
    composable(route = Screens.Splash.coreRoute) {
        SplashComposable(
            navigateToEstablish = {
                Screens.Establish.routeWithArgs?.let { route -> navController.navigate(route) }
            },
            navigateToHome = {
                navController.navigate(Screens.Home.coreRoute)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If your argument is supposed to be optional (i.e., using your default value if none is provided), why aren't you using the [syntax for optional arguments](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#optional-args)?

Comment: Good spot! have amended now and is working correctly